# Como fazer esse regex?

Tags: php, regex

Tenho algumas dificuldades usando REGEX, então gostaria de ajuda para separar o seguinte texto, exemplo:

```
1ª Temporada - Nome da temporada
01 - Nome do ep um
02 - Nome do ep dois
03 - Nome do ep três
...
2ª Temporada - Nome da temporada
01 - Nome do ep um
02 - Nome do ep dois
03 - Nome do ep três
...
```

Eu preciso fazer um `explode` e criar um array chamado `episodios` e dentro deste outros arrays, cada array correspondente a uma temporada, em prática seria:

```
$episodios = array();
$episodios[1] = array(
    1 => Nome do ep um
    2 => Nome do ep dois
    3 => Nome do ep três
);
$episodios[2] = array(
    1 => Nome do ep um
    2 => Nome do ep dois
    3 => Nome do ep três
);
```

A primeira chave em $episodios indica a temporada, e as chaves das temporadas indicam o número do episódio. Como posso fazer essa separação?

Abaixo um exemplo do texto original que devo separar:

```
1ª Temporada – Shinigami Daikou
001. O Dia em que me Tornei Shinigami
002. Um Trabalho de Shinigami
003. O Desejo do Irmão mais Velho, o Desejo da Irmã mais Nova
004. Periquito Amaldiçoado
2ª Temporada – Invasão a Soul Society
026. Formação! A Pior Companhia
027. Libere o Golpe Final!
028. Orihime está sendo Visada
3ª Temporada – Fuga da Soul Society
052. Renji, Juramento da Alma! Luta Mortal com Byakuya
053. A Tentação de Ichimaru Gin, Resolução da Destruição
054. Um Juramento Realizado! Pegue Rukia Devolta
```

Comment: Como esse texto vem para você? Através de um input? Ou é um arquivo .txt?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho é um arquivo txt, que leio e passo para uma variável todo o texto

Comment: O texto vem com esses 3 `...` mesmo?

Comment: @dvd o .... é pra dizer que pode ser que tenha mais episódios, e não só 3

Comment: Só pra constar Leo, eu nem ia falar, mas visto que talvez não tenha notado, se o seu texto estiver desordenado os scripts das demais respostas irão falhar, já o script que fiz em minha resposta, mesmo que o texto venha em ordem variadas, ainda sim ele consegue pegar o numero exato baseado na string de cada linha https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/290031/3635 - recomendo que mude a ordem dos episodios em cada temporada e teste todas respostas novamente, vai notar a diferença do comportamento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mesmo com regex será necessário fazer um loop, o regex sozinho não vai conseguir, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$filmes = array();

$str = '1ª Temporada – Shinigami Daikou
001. O Dia em que me Tornei Shinigami
002. Um Trabalho de Shinigami
003. O Desejo do Irmão mais Velho, o Desejo da Irmã mais Nova
004. Periquito Amaldiçoado
2ª Temporada – Invasão a Soul Society
026. Formação! A Pior Companhia
027. Libere o Golpe Final!
028. Orihime está sendo Visada
3ª Temporada – Fuga da Soul Society
052. Renji, Juramento da Alma! Luta Mortal com Byakuya
053. A Tentação de Ichimaru Gin, Resolução da Destruição
054. Um Juramento Realizado! Pegue Rukia Devolta';

$linhas = preg_split('#[\r\n]+#', $str);

$ultima_temporada = 0;

foreach ($linhas as $value) {

    //Extrai o numero da temporada
    if (preg_match('#(\d+)ª[^a-z]+?temporada#i', $value, $temporada)) {

        $ultima_temporada = intval($temporada[1]);
        $filmes[$ultima_temporada] = array();

    //Extrai o nome e numero do episodio
    } elseif (preg_match('#(\d+)[^a-z]+([a-z].*?)$#i', $value, $episodio)) {

        $filmes[$ultima_temporada][ intval($episodio[1]) ] = $episodio[2];

    }
}

//Exibe
print_r($filmes);
```

A variavel `$ultima_temporada` contém a ultima temporada encontrada, e no proximo loop se achar episódio será ela no array que irá receber os episódios, se a proxima linha for uma temporada então ele irá atualizar a variável para que só a proxima temporada receba os valores e assim por diante.

Já o `intval($episodio[1])` converte o valor do numero do episódio para inteiro (para não ter o zero a frente)

Exemplo no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/FHiOSg). Saída:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Nome do ep um
            [2] => Nome do ep dois
            [3] => Nome do ep três
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Nome do ep um
            [2] => Nome do ep dois
            [3] => Nome do ep três
        )

)
```

---

### Regex

Explicando a regex que extrai a temporadas:

```
(\d+)ª[^a-z]+?temporada

 ^    ^
 .    .
 .    .
 .    .
 .    .
 .    . 
 .    .... verifica se existe algum separador entre temporada
 .
 .... Pega o numero da temporada
```

Explicando a regex que extrai os episódios:

```
(\d+)[^a-z]+([a-z].*?)$

 ^    ^       ^       ^
 .    .       .       .
 .    .       .       ... Para ir até o final da string
 .    .       .
 .    .       ..... Para pegar qualquer coisa, no caso o nome do episódio
 .    . 
 .    .... Identifica se existe um separador, ou seja o espaço é opcional
 .
 .... Pega o numero do episódio
```

Comment: Gostei da explicação! Muito bom!

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, porém tive que remover essa parte \s?[\-] no primeiro IF, pois em minha página pois não estava funcionando com o texto real que tenho

Comment: @LeoLetto me manda este texto por favor

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei de adicionar a pergunta, um pedaço do texto original

Comment: @LeoLetto isso `–` não é um hífen, ou seja é diferente disto `-`, vou ajustar a regex - ps: os nomes dos episódios também não tem haver com o exemplo, são muito diferentes os separadores.

Comment: Sim, usei aquele mais simples como exemplo pois gostaria de ter apenas a base para fazer uma separação do gênero, e olhando o teu exemplo mesmo que diferente, eu consegui ajustar para o meu uso real :) obrigado mesmo pela explicação!

Comment: @LeoLetto mudei as regex para que funcionem independente destes problemas, veja a edição. IDEONE: https://ideone.com/FHiOSg

Answer (score 7):

Eu fiz sem REGEX, pois acho mais fácil.

```
$text =    "1ª Temporada - Nome da temporada
            01 - Nome do ep um
            02 - Nome do ep dois
            03 - Nome do ep três
            2ª Temporada - Nome da temporada
            01 - Nome do ep um
            02 - Nome do ep dois
            03 - Nome do ep três
            ";

$texto = explode("\n", $text);
$episodios = array();
$y = -1;
for( $x = 0; $x < count($texto); $x++){
    if(stristr($texto[$x], 'Temporada')){
        $y++;
        $episodios[$y] = array();
    } else {
        $episodios[$y][] = trim($texto[$x]);
    }
}
print_r($episodios);
```

Uma outra opção seria fazer assim:

```
$text = fopen("text.txt", "r"); // seu arquivo que contém o texto
$episodios = array();
$y = -1;
while(!feof($text)){
    $linha = fgets($text, 1024);
    if(stristr($linha, 'Temporada')){
        $y++;
        $episodios[$y] = array();
    } else {
        $episodios[$y][] = trim($linha);
    }
}

print_r($episodios);
```

Comment: esse `<br />` poderia ser trocado por "\n",

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim... Eu não tinha certeza. Vou trocar.

Comment: outra sugestão, troque isto `$episodios[$y][] = $texto[$x];` por isto `$episodios[$y][] = trim($texto[$x]);` e isto `$episodios[$y][] = $linha;` por isto `$episodios[$y][] = trim($linha);`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar este regex também:

```
$pattern = "/[\d].*/";
```

Ele irá pegar cada linha que inicia com um número criando uma array no índice `[0]` da captura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida você pode montar a array com `preg_match_all` e `foreach` (semelhante ao `while` da outra resposta):

```
$texto = '
1ª Temporada - Nome da temporada
01 - Nome do ep um
02 - Nome do ep dois
03 - Nome do ep três
2ª Temporada - Nome da temporada
01 - Nome do ep um
02 - Nome do ep dois
03 - Nome do ep três
';

$pattern = "/[\d].*/";
$resultado = preg_match_all($pattern, $texto, $matches);

$episodios = array();

$x = 1;
foreach($matches[0] as $items){
   if(stristr($items, 'Temporada')){
      $episodios[$x] = array();
      $x++;
   }else{
      $episodios[$x-1][] = $items;
   }
}

print_r($episodios);
```

[**Veja no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/RfRN4s)